# Connect to a Wireless WIFI Network through Robot Framework ( Windows and Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

i have an Issue :
i want to connect to another WIFI during a Test,

in Windows Command Line , this is working:

> netsh wlan connect name=name_of_wifi

and in ubuntu:

> nmcli c down connection_Name

but how i can run these through Robot Framework as a Test Step, when i'm in windows or ubuntu, and which library i need:

```
*** Settings ***
Library Selenium2Library
Library Process
*** Variables ***
*** Test Cases ***
Login in
Run Process python -c print 'Hello, world!'
?
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Run Process`?

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

```
Run Process    netsh    wlan    connect    name\=Free\ Wifi
```

In this example there is a space in the wifi SSID and you can escape it with the backslash. And the backslash before the equal sign make that Run Process doesn't use name as its own variable (see [Robot framework Run Process documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html))